# Need help to create mysql query for multiple selects for specific conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help to make a SQL query.
I have table 'stock_exchange' which records the stock interchanged between four different stores/sites.
It records

> date, item_id, qty, price, total_price, from_site, to_site

Now I need to create a query to run for one of the stores/site which will return total price for the stock sent and received between other three stores.
For example: there are Store1, Store2, Store3, Store4
If I need to check for Store1, it should return:

> **Store Name____Total Sent____Total Received**
>  Store2_________90.90_______50
>  Store3_________120_______100.40
>   Store4_________400_______200

I tried myself, but was only able to get sum of either stock sent or received.

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7e4c/3)

**EDIT:**
I changed the table to record store id (1,2,3,4....) now instead of store alias (crw, chc, cal_rav....), and the code(in answer) I accepted, has stopped working. I tried this amendment in the code to find matching rows by store id, but does't return anything:

```
SELECT GREATEST(t2.name, t3.name) AS from_store,
       LEAST(t2.name, t3.name) AS to_store,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.name < t3.name THEN t1.total_price ELSE 0 END) AS total_sent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.name > t3.name THEN t1.total_price ELSE 0 END) AS total_received
FROM stock_exchange t1
INNER JOIN sites t2
    ON t1.from_site = t2.id
INNER JOIN sites t3
    ON t1.to_site = t3.id
GROUP BY GREATEST(t2.name, t3.name),
         LEAST(t2.name, t3.name)
HAVING MAX(GREATEST(t2.id, t3.id)) = '1'
```

> Here is the [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c67d3d/5).

Comment: What is the logic behind this, in your fiddle ther are no values Shop1, Shop2, ...

Comment: there is no shop1, shop2..., ive mentioned store1, store2....to give the example, actual store names can be found in the fiddle

Comment: It were nice if the result you Show here depends on the data in your fiddle

Comment: in the fiddle, table stock exchange is recording store alias which, in the results, finds the actual store name by inner joining the stores table. everything is there in the fiddle to understand it. I didn't want to make the question very complex by saying all this.

Comment: Again. here is no value Store2 in this table: (1, 'Cafe Rosewood', 'crw'),
(2, 'Cafe Hillside', 'chc'),
(6, 'Cafe Rave', 'cal_rav'),
(8, 'Cafe Daneng', 'cal_dng');

Comment: my friend, as I said before (store1, store2...) is for example purpose only to make the question easily understandable, actual store names are the one's you just found in the fiddle (Cafe Rosewood.....)

Comment: For us it is easier to use the real names and vales here, so that we can see if our query is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query which shows the sent and received amounts from Cafe Rosewood to all other stores:

```
SELECT GREATEST(t2.name, t3.name) AS from_store,
       LEAST(t2.name, t3.name) AS to_store,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.name < t3.name THEN t1.total_price ELSE 0 END) AS total_sent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.name > t3.name THEN t1.total_price ELSE 0 END) AS total_received
FROM stock_exchange t1
INNER JOIN sites t2
    ON t1.from_site = t2.alias
INNER JOIN sites t3
    ON t1.to_site = t3.alias
GROUP BY GREATEST(t2.name, t3.name),
         LEAST(t2.name, t3.name)
HAVING MAX(GREATEST(t2.name, t3.name)) = 'Cafe Rosewood'
```

If you want to see transactions between *all* stores, just remove the `HAVING` clause.  This query employs a trick of taking `GREATEST(from_site, to_site)` to group together two stores.

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Thanks tim, can you please somehow join the table 'sites'to get the actual name of the stores instead of their alias

Comment: hi tim, ive just updated the store alias from varchar to int, cant get results based on the site id now which was based on store name before (Cafe Rosewood).....http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e85eb5/2

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, while there is possibility to have much wider combinations of multiple stores, I prefer using rather more queries that are more simple (and usually even faster to execute):

```
SELECT name, SUM(total_price) as total_sent_to FROM stock_exchange se 
LEFT JOIN sites ON sites.alias = se.to_site
WHERE from_site = 'crw' GROUP BY from_site, to_site;
SELECT name, SUM(total_price) as total_received_from FROM stock_exchange se
LEFT JOIN sites ON sites.alias = se.from_site
WHERE to_site = 'crw' GROUP BY from_site, to_site;
```

Result:

[image]

... so I would test it against bigger data amounts and compare solutions before using in production.

For counting totals:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(total_price)
                  FROM stock_exchange se 
                  WHERE se.from_site = sites.alias 
                  GROUP BY se.from_site) 
                as total_sent_sum,
                (SELECT SUM(total_price)
                  FROM stock_exchange se 
                  WHERE se.to_site = sites.alias 
                  GROUP BY se.to_site) 
                as total_received_sum
                FROM sites;
```

[image]

Comment: As this is returning total sent and total received for each store, can you please provide a query to get: how much Cafe Rosewood sent to and received from each of the other stores (relatively)???

Comment: @sohal07 Tim has already answered your additional question :)

Comment: I thank you for answering very fast, but if u read the question, same scenario was asked in the example "Now I need to create a query to run for one of the stores/site which will return......". Please don't mind I have full respect for you and your time given to help me

Comment: Thanks, anyway I updated my answer. Try if you are open to other solutions.